# GNU Parallel: redirect piped stdin as if it were a file

Tags: gnu-parallel

Suppose I have the following command to be parallelized:

```
my_command --file <(my | pipeline)
```

Now, I would like to parallelize in specific chunks:

```
my | pipeline | parallel --spreadstdin my_command --file <(parallel's stdin)
```

How would I accomplish this redirection with gnu parallel?

Comment: If your program does not read from STDIN, then you can use `--fifo` and `--cat`. If the question is re-opened I will post an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand this right, `parallel --spreadstdin` sends the blocks of input piped to the stdin of the processes it runs, so it's not Parallel's stdin you want `my_command` to read from, but its own.

If `my_command` doesn't default to reading stdin, you can usually use `/dev/stdin` in place of a filename, it resolves to the same file/pipe as the "original" stdin.

So

```
my | pipeline | parallel --spreadstdin my_command --file /dev/stdin
```

should be what you want.

Comment: its kind of a "why would you want to do that" situation, until you are slinging around a bunch of codes you don't have time to edit, all with different input interfaces.  Thanks man